# Formulario Sizable a traves de Picturebox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola chic@s tengo una aplicación en `FormBorderStyle = None`, lo que viene siendo sin ventana de windows.

Ya tengo como hacer para mover la ventana. El problema que tengo es poder redimensionar al gusto la aplicación, ya que en los bordes tengo `PictureBox` en forma de lineas en las 4 paredes por lo que no puedo redimensionar.

Estoy buscando la forma de redimensionar a través de esas lineas `PictureBox` como si del borde se tratase, pero no consigo.

tengo esto, pero solo sirve si no están las `PictureBox` en las paredes del form.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    private const int cGrip = 16;
    private const int cCaption = 32;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x84)
        {
            Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
            pos = this.PointToClient(pos);

            if (pos.Y < cCaption)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)2;
                return;
            }

            if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)17;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Llevo horas buscando por internet alguna solución pero no encuentro nada.
Gracias :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las lineas blancas son los `PictureBox` y debajo hay un `TabControl` que sobresale de abajo y de la derecha para que los bordes del `TabControl` no se vean, por lo que debajo del `PictureBox` está el `TabControl` y debajo el form.

UPDATE:

```
private void pictureBox11_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.X <= 2 && e.Y <= 2) || (e.X + 2 >= this.Width && e.Y + 2 >= this.Height))
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
        }
        else if ((e.X + 2 >= this.Width && e.Y <= 2) || (e.X <= 2 && e.Y + 2 >= this.Height))
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
        }
        else if (e.X <= 2 || e.X + 2 >= this.Width)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
        }
        else if (e.Y <= 2 || e.Y + 2 >= this.Height)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

He encontrado este código pero le faltan algúnas cosas, voy a ver si puedo hacer que funcione.

Comment: no entiendo, porque quieres hacer esto ? no tiene sentido cuando la ventana ya tiene capacidad de redimensionarse, es como querer reinventar la rueda

Comment: La ventana ya tiene sí, pero al haber un objeto donde está el lugar de redimensionar pues no deja. Ademas no quiero tener un formulario con la ventana de windows mas que nada por estetica ya que en windows 7 por ejemplo se ve bastante feo, windows 10 podria pasarlo por alto, aunque esa no es la cuestión. Como podria pasarle los controles de redimension a los picturebox de las paredes del form?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es colocar tus PictureBox con la propiedad Enabled=false, De esa manera no interfieren en el evento.

Comment: El problema es que por debajo de los picturebox también hay paneles y cosas que se salen del form de derecha y abajo por lo que esta solución no serviría, pero muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías agregar un ejemplo completo de un código que pueda correr y y ver exactamente a que te refieres.

Comment: win7 se ve con el estilo de win7, no se si sera feo o no, es cuestion del estilo de esa version. No entendi eso del "objeto en el lugar de la redimensionar", a que te refieres? no hay controles de redimensionar que le pases a picturebox, eso no existe. Lo unico que puedes hacer es con algun evento cambiar el Width o Height del form, pero no se cual podria ser ese evento

Comment: Eso es lo que busco que a traves del picturebox puedas iniciar un evento para redimensionar Width y Height del form.

Comment: El codigo expuesto sirve si no hay nada que tape el form.

Comment: Tal vez se pueda hacer un mix con esta info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575216/how-to-move-and-resize-a-form-without-a-border

Comment: Tiempo atrás vi una opcion deponer un SizeGripStyle, eso podria servirme, pero no encuentro donde lo vi :S